# XCode: The private key for "<foo> (from '<bar>')" is not installed on this Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have previously developed and released an iOS App with 'Company A'. Company A has just recently transferred ownership of the Application to 'Company B' (as per the instructions at the bottom of [this iOS developer document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW6)). This worked fine and the App now shows up in iTunes Connect under Company B's account.

I am now attempting to release an update for the App and having problems with XCode. I have removed all previous accounts from XCode, added the Company B account, build the new App and archived it, but when I try to 'Validate' or 'Distribute' from the XCode organiser, I get the error

> The private key for "Company A (from 'Company B')" is not installed on this Mac.

[image: XCode Code Signing Error Screenshot]

I have tried removing all iPhone Developer and iPhone distribution certificates from my Keychain, then revoking the Company B developer and distribution certificates, then re-creating them and installing them in my Keychain, but the error is the same.

What do I need to do to correct this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to solve this problem, as you've indicated, is to make a new provisioning profile from a newly generated public/private key pair.

Another way to solve this problem is to export the settings (ie private key) from a previous installation of Xcode (if you still have them) and port them to the new installation. In 'Organizer' choose 'Export Settings'.

The latter option is useful in a multi-member team scenario where you'd like to avoid disrupting other team members.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to resolve this issue by creating a completely new provisioning profile in the iTunes Connect Provisioning Portal, then signing the code with that profile.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Distribution certificate, then edited my existing provisioning profile to point to that new certificate, then in Xcode > preferences > account > view details I updated my signing certificates.

worked like a charm